# How to hide empty accordion content (ACF & Elementor)?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, accordion, elementor

I have this accordion in elementor that populates info from ACF fields.

```
<div class="elementor-accordion" role="tablist">

<div class="elementor-accordion-item">
<div id="elementor-tab-title-8611" class="elementor-tab-title elementor-active" data-tab="1" role="tab" aria-controls="elementor-tab-content-8611" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">
<span class="elementor-accordion-icon elementor-accordion-icon-left" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="elementor-accordion-icon-closed"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
<span class="elementor-accordion-icon-opened"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
</span>
<a class="elementor-accordion-title" href=""></a>
</div>

<div class="elementor-accordion-item">
<div id="elementor-tab-title-8612" class="elementor-tab-title" data-tab="2" role="tab" aria-controls="elementor-tab-content-8612" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="elementor-accordion-icon elementor-accordion-icon-left" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="elementor-accordion-icon-closed"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
<span class="elementor-accordion-icon-opened"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></span>
</span>
<a class="elementor-accordion-title" href=""></a>
</div>
<div id="elementor-tab-content-8612" class="elementor-tab-content elementor-clearfix" data-tab="2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="elementor-tab-title-8612"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

I'd like to hide the tabs when their content is empty. I used this snippets but nothing happend, the first and second snippests are for hid the tab automatically, the third snipped is for add "is-emty" class to emty tabs.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $emptyDivs = $(".elementor-accordion-item > div.elementor-tab-content:empty");
  $emptyDivs.each(function(){
    $(this).parent('div.elementor-accordion-item').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

```
<script>
var $span = $(".elementor-accordion-item > div.elementor-tab-content:empty");
$span.parent('div').hide();
</script>
```

```
<script> 
$(".elementor-tab-content").each(function(){ 
    if($(this).html().trim()==""){
        $(this).closest(".elementor-accordion-item").addClass("is-empty");
    }
});
</script>
```